# Toggling CSS using toggleClass() doesn't work for dynamically added rows

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating rows dynamically in a table of id = example. After creating, I want toggle CSS of each row upon `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. I do this using `toggleClass` as follows:

```
$("#example").on("mouseenter","tr",function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("hoverClass");
});

$("#example").on(".mouseleave","tr",function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("hoverClass");
});
```

In `<style>` section, I have:

```
.hoverClass
{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Now when I actually hover, classes are getting toggled to the rows but CSS doesn't get changed. Chrome shows strike-out over added CSS. Please see below.
[image]

Please advice.

Comment: there is something applying an inline style to that tr, if you want your class to overwrite the inline style, you need to use `!important`

Comment: Try
.hoverClass{
background-color: yellow !important;
}
The inline style is overwriting .hoverClass properties.

Comment: @jagdish.narkar Thanks a lot.  It worked! I didn't not know about !important. I see that I have added inline style when creating rows dynamically.

Comment: @SKG Looking at the image you provided you can see that `<tr class="ForOnlyOneSearch>` have a style tag, with the value `background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);`, which is the element style that override your class style.

Answer (score 0):

You hardcoded the yellow style into the html. Add the initial styling with jQuery, or else use a more exact selector in the script, or also add !important as suggested.